# Grok filter/pattern to extract the common and required attributes irrespective of order from logs

Tags: logging, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

For our application logs there will be some additional attributes generated based on the api call or request made along with the regular attributes. Some have same attributes but shuffled.

We have to extract the some common attributes from logs irrespective of order. using grok filter for this but stuck at getting required attributes from logs.

log

```
VERSION=>HTTP/1.1, X_IP=>16.12.18.14, PROTO=>https, PORT=>443,
HOST=>test.com, TRACE_ID=>1234561236,
TIME_ZONE_ABBREVIATION=>EDT, USER_EMAIL=>Email email=test@test.com, USER_AGENT=>test/1,
OS=>11, TIME_ZONE_NAME=>Europe/London, PLATFORM=>test
```

log with additional attributes

```
VERSION=>HTTP/1.1, X_IP=>16.12.18.14, PROTO=>https, PORT=>443,
HOST=>test.com, TRACE_ID=>326565654545454,
TIME_ZONE_ABBREVIATION=>EDT, USER_AGENT=>test/1,
OS=>11, NETWORK_TYPE=>type,DID=>C123456789, USER_EMAIL=>Email email=test@test.com
ZONE_NAME=>America/New_York, PLATFORM=>test,ENCODING=>gzip
```

Is there a way to extract the common and required attributes irrespective of order using grok pattern for parsing?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that since the first example data has a comma after the email address the section one would have a comma if you had not deleted it while redacting the email address.

The simplest solution is not to use grok at all, but to use a kv filter.

```
kv { field_split => "," value_split_pattern => "=>" trim_key => " " }
```

will result in

```
              "PLATFORM" => "test",
                  "PORT" => "443",
              "ENCODING" => "gzip",
```

etc. If you really want to use grok you can match against a separate pattern for each attribute

```
    grok {
        break_on_match => false
        match => {
            "message" => [
                "VERSION=>(?<version>[^,]+),",
                "X_IP=>(?<x_ip>[^,]+),",
                "PROTO=>(?<proto>[^,]+),",
                "PORT=>(?<port>[^,]+),",
                "HOST=>(?<hostname>[^,]+),",
                "TRACE_ID=>(?<trace_id>[^,]+),",
                "TIME_ZONE_ABBREVIATION=>(?<tz>[^,]+),",
                "USER_AGENT=>(?<userAgent>[^,]+),",
                "OS=>(?<os>[^,]+),",
                "NETWORK_TYPE=>(?<networkType>[^,]+),",
                "DID=>(?<did>[^,]+),",
                "USER_EMAIL=>(?<userEmail>[^,]+),",
                "ZONE_NAME=>(?<zoneName>[^,]+),",
                "PLATFORM=>(?<platform>[^,]+),",
                "ENCODING=>(?<encoding>[^,]+)(,|$)"
            ]
        }
    }
```

If that comma really is not there then you would change the USER_EMAIL pattern to use a lookahead that matches the pattern for a key.

If the order of attributes were fixed, but some were optional, so that you could have

```
FOO=>1, BAR=>2, BAZ=>3
FOO=>5, BAZ=>175
```

then you could use a pattern surrounded by ()? so that there is zero or more of it.

```
FOO=>%{NUMBER:foo},( BAR=>%{NUMBER:bar},)? BAZ=>%{NUMBER:baz}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked for us but not complete. The order of attributes changes in logs based on the request even though main attributes remains same.